# Passing Values into Memory location Access Violation in Assembly

Tags: assembly, access-violation, masm

I will start with this block of code:

```
mov   eax, 5
mov   DWORD PTR [eax], 123
```

I am trying to move the value 123 into the memory location at address 5, but I get a write access violation.  The only thing I can guess is that the memory location is already reserved or in use.  But no matter what address I use, it's the same thing.  If I were to read out from the same location, say:

```
mov   eax, 5
mov   ebx, DWORD PTR [eax]
```

I get no errors.  What am I missing?

(If it helps, I am coding in MASM, Win 7, 4 gb ram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a protection fault because your process doesn't own that particular piece of address space. In fact, the first megabyte of address space is made off limits by Windows for any process.

Comment: Though I think it's weird that do don't get an access violation *reading* from the same address, you should.

Comment: Thanks Jens, it's very helpful to know that the first meg is owned by Windows, of which I did not know.  But whatever address I use, I get the same access violation, but reading is not a problem. :/

Comment: @Eddie: You need to make sure the OS knows about the memory you try to use - your process has a virtual address space which the OS translates to real addresses in memory. To get a valid address you can either use the stack (pointed to by `esp`), [declare variables](http://www.etfos.unios.hr/~jbognar/pozadine/temp/asembly%20tutorial/x86asm/asml1002.html) or heap (with `malloc`/`VirtualAlloc`).

Comment: @Jens.  Just trying to learn how to use pointers in assembly.

Comment: Then I suggest you begin using allocated memory addresses. Either static or dynamic memory, as Matthew tells.

Comment: @Matthew. Thanks for the response.  You absolutely rock.  Using esp gave me a valid address.  I am guessing I would need to pop it when I am done, as loading the address pointed to at esp is like calling push.  I knew that I could declare a variable and effectively get the job done, I just wanted to learn as a matter of exercise, indirection in assembly.  Again a million thanks for solving my problem.  And thanks to you too Jens.

Comment: "loading the address pointed to at esp is like calling push" No. Please consult a tutorial, as you clearly are confused about the basics. But you can `push` any register/value to the stack to get a memory cell to experiment with. But don't forget to `pop` it when you are done.

Comment: @Jens, I just popped the stack and it contained the value I inserted at esp.  I am clearly confused about the the basics, of course, which is why I am here, but now only more confused by your response and the result I got from popping the stack.  If you have a good tutorial in mind that addresses what I am talking about, it would be nice if you pointed me to it.  ;)

Comment: Could also be that you understand the concepts but confuse the terminology. Anyway, Art of assembly is a good place to start.

Comment: @Jens, awesome.  Thanks for sticking this out with me.  Cheers.  :)